# Wordpress drag posts and pages so you can order them

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

So has anyone done this? can be done? On wordpress admin, when you click List Pages, or List posts, I want to make a drag&drop in order to sort the pages/posts, but before I start I want to know if someone has done it already, or if there is a plugin for this.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.  Maybe you're expected to ask on the WordPress stack exchange?  But regardless - we use the [My Page Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-page-order/) plugin to sort pages.

Comment: +1 @Hobo - That plugin can be easily manipulated for posts, and that is the way that I would go.